# SLD file exported from QGIS not working in Geoserver?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, symbology, sld

I understand that others have encountered the problem of SLD exports running in Geoserver, and I have taken several steps recommended elsewhere on this site to fix the code but it still won't run, so if anyone can spot any glaring errors in the below, code sample, please let me know.  The only error message I receive when I use the validate function in the Geoserver is:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 47; The prefix "sld" for element "sld:CssParameter" is not bound.

```
enter code here<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" units="mm"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/
http://schemas.opengis.net//1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
<NamedLayer>
<Name>nyc_bike_routes_2017</Name>
<UserStyle>
  <Name>nyc_bike_routes_2017</Name>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name></Name>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#0cc38c</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>I, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>I, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>I</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#00a884</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>I, L</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>I, L</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>I</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>L</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#55ff00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">centralPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>I, R</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>I, R</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>I</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>R</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#4ce600</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">firstPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>I, II, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>I, II, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>I,II</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>lanecount</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#4ce600</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>I, III, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>I, III, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>I,III</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#4ce600</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>I, III, L</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>I, III, L</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>I,III</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>L</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#4ce600</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">centralPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
              <Rotation>
                <ogc:Literal>180</ogc:Literal>
              </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>II, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>II, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>II</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>lanecount</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>II, L</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>II, L</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>II</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>L</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#e31a1c</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">centralPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
              <Rotation>
                <ogc:Literal>180</ogc:Literal>
              </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>II, R</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>II, R</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>II</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>R</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#e31a1c</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">centralPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>II, I, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>II, I, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>II,I</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>lanecount</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#4ce600</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>II, III, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>II, III, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>II,III</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>lanecount</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#e31a1c</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>II, III, L</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>II, III, L</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>II,III</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>L</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#e31a1c</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">firstPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
              <Rotation>
                <ogc:Literal>180</ogc:Literal>
              </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>III, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>III, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>III</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>lanecount</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>III, L</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>III, L</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>III</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>L</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">firstPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
              <Rotation>
                <ogc:Literal>180</ogc:Literal>
              </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>III, R</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>III, R</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>III</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>bikedir</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>R</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <VendorOption name="placement">centralPoint</VendorOption>
        <Stroke>
          <GraphicStroke>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                  <:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</:CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicStroke>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>III, I, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>III, I, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>III,I</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>lanecount</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#4ce600</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>III, II, 2</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>III, II, 2</Title>
      </Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>allclasses</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>III,II</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>lanecount</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#e31a1c</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-2</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke">#ffaa00</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</:CssParameter>
          <:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</:CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Comment: A suggestion, pick the latest version of both programs (qgis 2.18, geoserver 2.11), you should have an easier time (though best compatibility requires the development version of both).

Answer (score 2):

I know people complain that Open Source programs have cryptic error messages but this one is quite clear.

```
The prefix "sld" for element "sld:CssParameter" is not bound.
```

So on line 12 you have used the `sld` prefix on your `CssParameter` but you have not defined it anywhere, so GeoServer is confused by what you mean. Since you have defined the SLD namespace to be your default namespace, that's what

```
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
```

means, you can just delete all the `sld:` bits from your sld and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Iant, I'm embarrassed I didn't catch that.

I removed those tags but for whatever reason the layer is still not symbolizing.  

My next recourse is to do what another commenter advised and try exporting the SLD in the most recent version of QGIS and updating our Geoserver version, which on dev is 2.8-SNAPSHOT.  Speaking of which, does anyone know what "SNAPSHOT" means in this context?

My thanks to all.

Comment: A snapshot is just the state of the project on a particular day, you shouldn't really be using them for regular use.

Comment: Try changing filled arrow head to square and see if anything shows up.

Comment: Interesting, iant. I followed your advice and the squares did show up.

Comment: Then geoserver does not know about filled arrows, that might be one of the ones Andrea added recently so try an update

Comment: Thanks so much, iant.  I spoke to my project manager and we will update our dev Geoserver to the latest version..  Please see my comprehensive SLD file above -- what I am wondering is why only the squares went through and none of the other, seemingly-correct code. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You still have a : on the cssparameters